# RadControl disappear and unrecognized tag prefix

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

i need to enhance the application which developed by other colleagues, the source code located at share folder such as \10.1.1.1\App1
and i had map the share folder as network drive such as T: drive

my colleagues can open the apps by VS and work properly, but when i open it by VS2010, it cannot display the RadControl in Toolbox, display unrecognized tag prefix error message and cannot reference telerik function in code behind.

i had tried many methods that found on forum and website but doesn't work. e.g.

- Using Caspol.exe to grant .NET applications rights to a remote ...

Caspol.exe –m –ag 1.2 –url file://\10.1.1.13/App1/* FullTrust

Caspol.exe –m –ag 1.2 –url file://\T:/* FullTrust

- Add reference to web.config

- Remove dll from bin folder

Comment: Have you installed the Telerik add-on for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

refer Telerik.Web.UI assembly and register the tagprefix in the web.config or directly into the page:

```
 <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
```

or in the aspx page:

```
  <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
```